# Require email textfield to have @ character

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

When a user registers I need the email field to detect whether or not the field has a valid email in it (must have the @ symbol). How do I make the text field require this character in Swift? Such as Twitters signup.

https://twitter.com/signup

Comment: Your two current questions are both rather brief and overly broad for this site. We try to encourage people here to research the problem at hand, make an attempt, and then ask a focussed question if they get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to use NSNotification to monitor the user's input. Red hint keeps showing

[image]
until user input some string like`xxxx@xxx.com`, the hint goes off.
[image]
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var alertLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"textFieldChanged:", name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: emailTextField)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func textFieldChanged(sender:AnyObject) {
        var inputText = emailTextField.text
        var isValid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}").evaluateWithObject(inputText)
        if(isValid == false){
            alertLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            alertLabel.text = "Not a valid email address"
        }else {
            alertLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            alertLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used textfield "Editing did End" method for validation when leave textfield.

```
-(BOOL)NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES; 
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}

-(IBAction)emailValidation:(id)sender
{

    if ([self NSStringIsValidEmail:self.emailTextField.text]) {
        NSLog(@"Successful= login");
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Email" message:@"Please check your email " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alrt show];

    }

}
```

//Swift code

```
 @IBAction func emailValidation(sender: AnyObject) {

        if NSStringIsValidEmail(emailTextField.text) == true {
            println("Valid")
        //valid
        }
        else{
             println(" Not Valid")
            //invalid
        }

    }


    func NSStringIsValidEmail(checkString: NSString) ->Bool
    {

        var stricterFilter = true
        var stricterFilterString = "[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
         var laxString = ".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*"
        var  emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString

        var emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@" ,emailRegex)

        return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(checkString)
    }
```

[image]